# Change default terminal in VS Code to cmd

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open VS Code, the default terminal is PowerShell and the default path is `PS E:\Research\GM\Articles\Modularity\Covariance network\Graph theory\Metric basics\Consensus clustering\clustering_programs_5_2`.

Q1: How could I change the default path in PowerShell to C:\Users<UserName>? (red line below)

Q2: How could I change the default terminal from PowerShell to cmd? (yellow circle below)
[image]

#############################################################################
I followed Geeky's method which worked well. However, the default path is still `E:\Research\GM\Articles\Modularity\Covariance network\Graph theory\Metric basics\Consensus clustering\clustering_programs_5_2` rather than something like `C:\Users<UserName>`:
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Press **Ctrl + Shift + P**. Type "def" and the default terminal selection option pops.
[image]

Click on it and select your preferred terminal
[image]

---

Alternatively, add this in your `settings.json` file

```
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt",
```

If the following code exists already in your `settings.json` file or else add the following code also

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell": {
        "source": "PowerShell",
        "icon": "terminal-powershell",
        "path": "C:\\windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
    },
    "Command Prompt": {
        "path": ["${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe", "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"],
        "args": [],
        "icon": "terminal-cmd"
    },
}
```

Comment: I included your recommended settings in `settings.json` but that did not seem to change anything. I have edited my question to provide some details. Thank you.

Comment: After the modifications, have you tried deleting all the open terminals and opening a new one?

Comment: After reopening terminals, that worked. But the default path is still the previous one, not the `C:\Users<UserName>`. I have edited my question for more details. Thank you.

Comment: When you are opening a terminal in VSCode, it opens with the project's path. If you want to open a command prompt with the path `C:\Users<Username>`, type `C:` in there terminal, then `cd Users\<Username>`